# Displaying using JQuery UI Autocomplete not displaying results

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm using Jquery UI's autocomplete, and I can see the proper JSON data coming back in Firebug. However, nothing's coming back to the textbox.

My JavaScript:

```
$(function() {
        function log( message ) {
            $( "<div/>" ).text( message ).prependTo( "#log" );

        }

        $("#tags").autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response){
                    $.ajax ({
                url: "/projectlist",
                                dataType: "json",
                                data: {style: "full", maxRows: 12, term: request.term}
                            });
                                            }

    })
});
```

You can see that from the snippet JSON data is being returned. But nothing is being displayed in the results table. Which should look like the the JQuery autocomplete example [JQuery Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp)

[image: Snippet of what browser returns in firebug]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Noyhing is displayed because you return nothing i think: you must add e success function to your ajax call (i added an example of a success response, if you tell us how your json is tructured i could help you better. in any case you must return an array of objects, and each object should have a property named 'label' and one named 'value':

```
$("#tags").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/projectlist",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                style: "full",
                maxRows: 12,
                term: request.term
            },
            success: function(data) {
                var results = [];
                $.each(data, function(i, item) {
                    var itemToAdd = {
                        value: item,
                        label: item
                    };
                    results.push(itemToAdd);
                });
                return response(results);

            }
        });
    }
});
```

I set up a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/nicolapeluchetti/pRzTy/ (imagine that 'data' is the json that is returned)

Comment: `def project_list  
    list=Project.all.map{|i|i.project_name}
    arr= [].concat(list.sort{|a,b| a[0]<=>b[0]}).to_json
    render :json =>arr
  end`

Comment: Post what is returned in the browser

Comment: It returns the values in firebug but does not display it.

Comment: Something is wrong with the code you posted Nicola Peluchetti

Comment: `missing } after property list
[Break On This Error] success: function( data ) { `

Comment: sorri i was missing a comma after `data: {style: "full", maxRows: 12, term: request.term}` (couldn't test the ajax part unfortunately)

Comment: `missing } after property list
[Break On This Error] }); `

Comment: I've fixed the } but now it doesnt list anything in the autocomplete box

Comment: ok, checked here, now it should work http://jsfiddle.net/nicolapeluchetti/JKmru/ edited answer)

Comment: @AhmetAbdi let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1875/discussion-between-nicola-peluchetti-and-ahmet-abdi)

Comment: When I last asked you about listing one project to appear you mentioned that it was something to do with my server side and that I was returning all terms. Are you saying that Take the request var term and filter the list? Still struggling with this. Don't know how to fix this

Comment: Sorry but i'm on holiday right now, so i can't help you that much, but yes, i think that the problem lies in the fact that you don't filter the data server side and so all terms are returned. This means that you have to write the code server side that handles the logic that returns the correct terms accordin to what the user inputted!